# Mail scripts returns spreadsheet with login page rather than spreadsheet data

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-signin

I've got a script that needs to send a specific tab in my spreadsheet, this all works fine. The problem is with the attached .xls as it does not contain the data from the tab. it only contains text from the Google login page:

"One account. All of Google.
Sign in to continue to Sheets
Enter your email
Find my account

Sign in with a different account   Create account

One Google Account for everything Google"

I've tried injecting some functions in my code but couldn't fix the problem. I figure it needs to check my login credentials somewhere down the line?

I've added the line  var options = {'muteHttpExceptions': true} to get around a 404 error. Is this the root cause?

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();

  var email = Session.getUser().getEmail();

  var email_ID1 = "n@b.com";

  var subject = "Quotes";

  var body = "This is my message";

     var options = {'muteHttpExceptions': true}
     var shID = getSheetID("mail_Data") 
     var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
 var contents = result.getContent();

 MailApp.sendEmail(email_ID1,subject ,body, {attachments: 
 [{fileName:sheetName+".xls", content:contents, 
 mimeType:"application//xls"}]});


};
function getSheetID(mail_Data){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(mail_Data)
var sheetID = ss.getSheetId().toString() 
return sheetID
}
```

Expecting the script to check my credentials before returning the sheet.

Comment: You need to send Authorization header. Search apps script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL fetch needs to be authorised. And you can do it by getting an OAuth token and sending that in the header.

Try replacing this:

```
 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

with this:

```
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
  }
});
```

And you won't need:

```
 var options = {'muteHttpExceptions': true}
```

Comment: I have literally just fixed it myself in a rather more obscure way I think. Came to this:

`var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
  
  var headersOptions = {   
    Authorization : 'Bearer '  + token  
    };  
  
  var options = {   
    headers : headersOptions,  
    muteHttpExceptions : true  
    };  
    
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`